# Index catalogrule_rule still invalid after reindex by cron

Tags: cron, indexer, magento2.3.6

I have an issue with indexes becoming invalid once a day even though nothing has changed (neither in front end or back end). When this happens all other indexes but `catalogrule_rule` and `catalog_category_product` get indexed by cron job (bin/magento cron:run) but these two remain invalid. In fact the do get reindexed but the moment `catalog_category_product` finishes all indexes become invalid again. All other but these two get reindexed quickly (because nothing has changed). And this goes on indefinitely. While this happens MySQL memory usage grows until eventualy after a coulpe of days it simply crashes and restarts.

I have tried reseting the indexes to no avail. Reindexing all indexes manually also does not help. Also tried switching some/all indexed to run by schedule instead of on save, and made no difference at all (that is to be expected as nothing was ever saved).

But if I manually reindex only `catalogrule_rule`, then everything goes back to normal for a day (until the time Magento decides to do a full reindex)

Any one have clues as to what could be wrong with my installation?

Background:

- Magento 2.3.6
- cron:run every 5 minutes
- Indexer cron settings inside magento adjusted to run every 5 min instead of every 1min
- Amasty ShopBy extensions installed
- VPS 8GB / 4 vCPU
- ~7K SKUs
- ~90 catalog rules

*Edit (14/6/21):*

One thing I noticed is that there are left over temporary tables (`catalogrule_product__tempXXXXXX`) and their number increases over time. My guess is that indexing somehow ends abruplty (either it ges killed or fails with some exception) but without logging any errors in Magento logs. This would explain the left over table but doesn't explain the memory usage (even if a process ends abruptly the connections get closed and any resources held by the process should be released). Also note that the number of active connections does not increase over time (but that could be attributed to connection pooling on PHP side)

I am having this issue with both the production server and a staging server (different providers, different configurations). Since I was planning to upgrade Magento I did so on the staging server to test.
After upgrading Magento from 2.3.6 to 2.4.2 the issue is gone (so far). So I am pretty confident this is an issue with Magento or one of the extensions and not with MySQL configuration. I can't tell if it is Magento itself or one of the extensions, because I had to upgrade those as well to be compatible with 2.4.2.

Comment: Could you post A) the last 400 lines of your MySQL error.log and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE catalog_category_product; and C) SHOW INDEX FROM catalog_category_product?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to MySQL logs on the server. I will try to replicate the issue locally and get the logs.

Comment: Could you get your hosting company to provide the logs to you?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this year old question related to index destruction? Thanks

Comment: I never managed to reproduce the issue with 2.4.2, so upgrading solved this for me.

Comment: Would you like to improve performance of MySQL or MariaDB in completing your queries?  View profile for contact info and free Utility Scripts to assist.